# Django Pagination too slow with large dataset

Tags: python, mysql, django, database, pagination

I have a problem regarding Django's Pagination. When I try to paginate over 200k records the portal Web load very slow (>10 secs), and I'm suppose to use around 2 million records.

I can't find on Stackoverflow or other site a GOOD specific fix to this problem. Everytime the code gets a page it executes the QuerySet, which goes over a very large dataset, making it slow.

Anybody knows what can be done? I've searched everywhere and couldn't fix this issue. Below I post the code to paginate. Paper_list is: model.object.all().filter(category=x) (and there are around 200k objects now (all of them belong to that category too).

```
def paginate_context(paper_list, request, context, source, author, title, term, date):
num_papers = len(paper_list) 
paginator = Paginator(paper_list, 4) # Show X papers per page
page = request.GET.get('page')
try:
    papers = paginator.page(page)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
    papers = paginator.page(1)
except EmptyPage:
    # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of results.
    papers = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)      
context['papers'] = papers
context['num_papers'] = num_papers
context['query_cat'] = create_request_str_and(context['cat'], source, author, title, term, date)
```

Comment: Do you have an index on the field you're ordering your queryset by (or filtering on)?

Comment: I do. category = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=200). I know there may be a problem with the count, but I tried some ways to fix it without much success.

Comment: Could you look up the actual DB query (and get an `EXPLAIN SELECT` on it?). Maybe it's worth converting the `category` field intto a `ForeignKey`, but it's just a guess.

Comment: I ran the query with EXPLAIN before the SELECT. But I'm not sure how to interpret its result. After the EXPLAIN SELECT:  | category | NULL       | index | NULL          | category_1da45b5bea657362_uniq | 602     | NULL | 112172 |   100.00 | Using index |
+----+-------------+-------------------------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------------
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

Comment: I mean, you should `EXPLAIN` the slow query, not the empty `SELECT`. There's a handy service if you're using Postgresql: http://explain.depesz.com/ . Or is the result you've provided the actual explain result? Post it via dpaste or gist, please, it's unreadable.

Comment: I'm using mySQL. Maybe I didn't explain myself correctly. When I run the Query directly on mySQL it takes only 0.07 secs to execute (with index). But when I use the pagination it runs(the website & pagination) very slow. And every time I get a new page it takes many seconds to load too. I was told it could be because there is a query executed for every page that is requested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I can see in the code, `num_papers = len(paper_list)` method evaluates the query, hence could hamper performance. You can change it to:

```
num_papers = paper_list.count()
```

You can check here about when the queryset is evaluated: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated

Comment: ruddra, eagle-eye! ) That's definitely the real problem.

Comment: That is only an informative line of code to show how many results are there. I was told that could affect the performance. So I commented that line. The problem persisted. I tried what you suggested some time ago but it didn't improve the loading time.

Comment: Never mind. That DID fix the problem. Thanks!  Now I have another problem. model.objects.all().filter(category=context['cat']) Doesn't return all the records it should, since it only gives back records with 1 category. But each record can have several categories associated. This works:  [item for item in model.objects.all() if any(category in item.category for category in context['cat'])]  But the executing time is way too slow.

Comment: It would be better If you can ask another question about the new problem, so it can be more clearer :) . Please accept my answer so that it can be helpful to others in future :)

Comment: Will do a new question when it lets me, as I also tried fixing this last problem without much success (hence, the overworked used for() to obtain the right records). Accepted the answer, thanks again.